# Angular get ng-model properties eg. minlength

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I'm trying to make form validation in angular ( my 1st time ), and I got stucked in following moment:

I've made template with validation messages: `form_messages.html`

e.g. snippet from index.html

```
<input type="password" name="password" ng-model="password" ng-minlength="6" required>
<div class="form-error" role="alert"
     ng-messages="form.password.$error"
     ng-show="form.password.$invalid && form.$submitted || form.password.$dirty">
    <ng-messages ng-messages-include="/path/to/form_messages.html"></ng-messages>
</div>
```

e.g. messages in template form_messages.html

```
<p class="form-error__message" ng-message when="required">Password is required.</p>
<p class="form-error__message" ng-message when="minlength">Password needs to be at least 6 characters.</p>
```

Everything works pretty good, but I want it to be flexible for other inputs too.

What is the **best way** to accomplish this?

Something as following abstract snippet in form_messages.html would be wonderfull:

```
<p class="form-error__message" ng-message when="minlength">
    {{ ng-model.name }} needs to be at least {{ ng-model.minlength }} characters.
</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there is a feature request for this https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9849

---

For getting validators you can use $error object, for example for `minlength` it will be something like `form.$error.minlength[0].$name`. But, there is no way to get exact value of this validator yet. See this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11671.

You need to implement `ngModel` directive (code borrowed from the issue):

```
app.directive('ngModel', function attributeNgModelDirective() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, el, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$attributes = attrs;
    }
  };
});
```

Then you can use it as `form.$error.minlength[0].$attributes.minlength`

```
<p class="form-error__message" ng-message when="minlength">
    {{ form.$error.minlength[0].$name }} needs to be at least {{ form.$error.minlength[0].$attributes.minlength }} characters.
</p>
```

See the complete example: http://plnkr.co/edit/6u9v01AvBdAHhJwZOKtI?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for answer, but currently it don't cure my problem. I need to know What is the best way to accomplish this? It's not enough to say you need to write custom code. :) I need to know what is best practice approach to this, e.g. store min.length in service which is included to every form controller.

Comment: @Garrett the answer has been updated with working example

Comment: Thanks for complex solution :)